# Match all pattern occurences but not in double quotes

Tags: python, regex, r

I m trying to solve the next task.
E.g., I have a sentances like:

```
(1) "Je suis arrivé en Californie il y a quatre décennies 
avec absolument rien et grâce à l'accueil que cet Etat m'a offert, 
j'ai tout obtenu ", a-t-il dit dimanche dans son ultime allocution
hebdomadaire en tant que gouverneur.
(2) En revanche, je ne crois pas que l'on puisse engager durablement des soldats 
dans un conflit long et dur sans un soutien populaire fort.
(3) This is another sample with je and in double quotes "like je here" as well.
```

I need a regexp which matches the sentence if it contains 'Je' or 'je' but not surrounded by double quotes. Right now I m using the next regexp:

```
(.*)\s((^Je|je)|(Je|je))\s(.*)
```

But it also matches sentance when pattern is within double quotes.
For example, from sample above only (2) and (3) sentences should match the regexp.

Comment: Would the double quotes always be balanced?

Comment: this works for me in r `grep('(?i)je', gsub('\".*\"', '', tmp))` where `tmp` is a vector of your sentences. and also works for the examples in rohit's answer

Comment: You need to decide whether you are using R or Python. In R a character vector would always be displayed with leading and trailing double-quotes (which are really not there) and any really double-quote characters are escaped with backslashes. The regex pattern arguments are also different. At the moment you appear to be working in Python.

Comment: @rawr, this function is good only if you have one phrase on quotes in your text. Try to apply it for http://pastebin.com/cavp1VV8 and see the result.

Comment: @Alex of course I know that. like i said it works for your examples. all you have to do is make the subbing non greedy

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to search the pattern in the string:

```
s = 'This is another sample with je and in double quotes "like je here" as well.'    
re.search(r'[jJ]e(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', s)  # Match

s = 'This is another sample with and in double quotes "like je here" as well.'
re.search(r'[jJ]e(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', s)  # No match
```

This assumes you've balanced double quotes in your string.

Comment: Thank you, @Rohit. That works! Although, it is possible to handle some redundant quotes? Sometimes text may have odd quote(s) because of the typos which screw the result of regexp. Here is an example of such text with odd quote at the end: https://regex101.com/r/hZ5oW1/1 (here instead of matching outside the quotes it matches inside)

Comment: @Alex There is no way you can solve this for odd number of quotes. How would you know what pair of quotes are valid? So, it won't be possible to konw whether your text is really inside quotes or outside.